# Proof of Chevalley–Warning theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

How to prove Chevalley–Warning theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem) by using  Fulton's trace formula

(#$|X(\mathbb{F}_p)| \equiv \sum (-1)^i Tr(Frob_p|H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X)) \mod p$)?

Comment: I'm not sure it answers your question exactly, but do take a look at [David Speyer's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/52433/11619). Pete L. Clark and Akhil Matthew also add interesting things, but largely from a different point of view.